# How to scrape price data on page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

I am new to web scraping and is having trouble figuring out how to scrape all the prices in the webpage below. What I tried returns blank, any pointers would be great!

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import urllib.request


url = 'https://www.remax.ca/find-real-estate'
page = urlopen(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
price = soup.findAll('h3', {'class' : 'price'})
```

Comment: Did you print your `price` variable? `print(price)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, if you use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, don't use `import bs4` too.

Second, write `soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser`)

Then use `price = soup.find_all('h3',{'class':'price})`

After this, you should have in "price" all the prices, but you still need to refine, as in that form you will copy all that code from the h3s.

**EDIT**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.request


url = 'https://www.remax.ca/find-real-estate'
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
price = soup.find_all('h3', {'class' : 'price'})


for p in price:
    print(p.text)
```

This should do the job. I eliminated pandas because i have not it installed.